# sqlite join statement

Tags: database, sqlite

I'm just learning join statements in sqlite and I'm having trouble with the the below example.
Here is the statement that has gotten me closest to the results I want:

select listings.id, listings.name, media.image from listing join media where media.listing_id = listings.id

listings:

id  |  name  |  phone

1  ,    john   , 555-5555

2  ,    jane   , 555-0000

media:

listing_id  | image_url

2    ,      www.xyz.xyz

### in return I want

id  |  name  |  image_url

1    ,  john
   2    ,  jane    , www.xyz.xyz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be

```
SELECT listings.id, listings.name, media.image_url 
    FROM listing LEFT JOIN media ON media.listing_id = listings.id
```

A "left join" gives you results from the left table (listing) even if there is no match in the right table (media). A regular join requires both to exist to give a result for that row.